# Meteor.http.call: How do I assign the results of Meteor.http.call to a variable at server side?

Tags: meteor

I have the following code:

```js
Meteor.http.call("POST","/abcd/efd",{data:payload}, function (error,result) {
    if (error){
        //...
    } else { 
        myresult=result
    }
});
console.log("myresult-->",myresult) //myresult is undefined here
```

I cannot use session since the code is in server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling an asynchronous function, which is why the

```js
console.log("myresult-->",myresult) //myresult is undefined here
```

is called immediately after the `Meteor.http.call` has been executed, no matter whether the result has been received or not.

Since you are on the server side, however, you can easily call the synchronous version of http:

```js
import { HTTP } from 'meteor/http'

const myresult = HTTP.call("POST", "/abcd/efd", {data:payload});
console.log("myresult-->" my result) //myresult is defined here
```

More to read on: https://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html#HTTP-call